# Opencart get category_id in category page

Tags: php, opencart

Trying to get "new" sticker in category page. For example if product have category 219 it would have sticker.

What I have added in controller category.php

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['$product_id']);

$categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);

$this->data['category_id'] = $categories_info['category_id'];
```

In category.tpl

```
<?php if($category_id=="219") { ?>
<img src="new.jpg">
<?php } ?>
```

But nothing have appeared.

**UPD: change a code**

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);

    $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[3]['category_id']);

    $this->data['category_id'] = $categories_info['category_id'];
```

category.tpl

```
  <?php if ($category_id=="219") { ?>                           

            <?php } else {  ?>

            <?php } ?>
```

It works only if i use $categories[3]['category_id'] but I can't search value it array with php function in_array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want send some data for template you have to use $data array.

For example:

```
$data['category_id'] = $categories_info['category_id'];
```

Then call it in your templase using `$category_id`

Comment: I must say it is Opencart 1.5.